# Post sorting and ordering function in Wordpress Admin is broken and always shows post from oldest to newest

Tags: plugins, mysql

Hello I tried a plugin which automatically insert a pagebreak each # of words to split post into multiple posts. This plugin does not save the pagebreak in the database, it just insert the pagebreak on the fly when loading post so my posts were not changed in my database.

When i uninstalled the plugin, I found that post sorting in backend was broken and all my posts in backend wordpress admin are shown from oldest to newest without possibility of re-orderiing them.

If i click the date column in order to sort them from ascending to descending this does not work, simply nothing happens, page reaload with same order of posts. Also, the ordering function does not work anymore for the title column, if i click title column to order them alphabetically, page reloads and nothing changes, posts are always shown from oldest to newest.. This means that the sorting and ordering function of posts is broken for some reason.

This issue only happens in admin list of posts, not in the homepage, where the published date still works to sort them.

Also, the published date of the post was not changed by the plugin in my database, so something else is happening.

I tried to find plugins with ordering and sorting functions but I could not find a plugin that solve this problem.

Anyone has an idea on how to debug this, what could be causing this issue?

Also, is there any code I can add to functions.php in order to force wordpress to show posts in backend from newest to oldest?

Please help me i am getting crazy!

Comment: This seems like a very difficult issue to troubleshoot... Have you attempted the ol' tried and true "deactivate/reactivate plugins/themes one-by-one to see if the behavior changes" approach?

Comment: i solved it my problem was no space left on disk LOL

Comment: Haha - well done! I'm glad you sorted it out. There's not a snowball's chance in hell that I would have ever guessed that this issue could be related to disk space :P . How did you manage to pin disk space down as the problem, out of curiousity?

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved, the problem was no space left on disk, lol, sorry!